# Scanning bit array for pattern of multiple bits

Tags: c++, c++11, memory-management, bit-manipulation, dynamic-allocation

I am writing an memory allocator that is backed by a bit map (array of `uint8_t`) currently when an allocation request comes along I scan the bitmap sequential from 0 to n bits and search for a space that can fulfill the request. (a bit 1 denotes page used a 0 denoted page is free) Now instead of searching for a space one bit at a time is there technique to scan the whole array faster? i.e if a request for 3 page memory arrives I would like to search for `000` pattern in the array in one go ideally without looping?

PS: I am not using `std::bitset` as it is not available for the compiler I am using. AFAIK that does not let me search for multiple bits also.

EDIT: Bits are packed into bytes one `uint8_t` has 8 pages (1 per bit) encoded in it.

Answer (score 1):

To scan for one empty page, you could loop through the bit array one full byte at a time and check if it is smaller than 255. If it is smaller, there is at least one zero bit. Even better would be to scan 32 or 64 bit (unsigned ints) at a time, and then narrow the search inside the uint.

To optimize a bit, you could keep track of the first byte with a zero bit (and update that position when freeing a page). This could give a false positive once you allocate that free page, but at least the next time the scan can start there instead of at the beginning.

A scan for multiple pages could be optimized if you're willing to align larger blocks on a power of 2 (depending on your data structures). For example, to allocate 8 pages, you would only scan for a full byte being zero:

```
1 page: scan for any zero bit (up to 64 bits at a time)
2 pages: scan for 2 zero bits at bit position 0,2,4,6
3-4 pages: scan for zero nibble (for 3 pages, the fourth would be available for 1 page then)
5-8 pages: scan for an empty byte

for each of the above, you could first scan 64 bits at a time.
```

This way, you don't have to worry about (or check) overlapping zero ranges at byte/uint32/uint64 boundaries.

For each type a starting position with the first free block could be kept/updated.

Answer (score 1):

Not a full answer to your question (I suppose) but I hope that the following function can help.

```
template <typename I>
bool scan_n_zeros (I iVal, std::size_t num)
 {
   while ( --num )
      iVal |= ((iVal << 1) | I{1});

   return iVal != I(-1);
 }
```

It return (if I've written it correctly) `true` **if** (not where) there are at least `num` consecutive zero bit in `iVal`.

The following is a full working example when `T` is `uint8_t`

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename I>
bool scan_n_zeros (I iVal, std::size_t num)
 {
   while ( --num )
      iVal |= ((iVal << 1) | I{1});

   return iVal != I(-1);
 }

int main()
 {
   uint8_t  u0 { 0b00100100 };
   uint8_t  u1 { 0b00001111 };
   uint8_t  u2 { 0b10000111 };
   uint8_t  u3 { 0b11000011 };
   uint8_t  u4 { 0b11100001 };
   uint8_t  u5 { 0b11110000 };

   std::cout << scan_n_zeros(u0, 2U) << std::endl; // print 1
   std::cout << scan_n_zeros(u0, 3U) << std::endl; // print 0
   std::cout << scan_n_zeros(u1, 4U) << std::endl; // print 1
   std::cout << scan_n_zeros(u1, 5U) << std::endl; // print 0
   std::cout << scan_n_zeros(u2, 4U) << std::endl; // print 1
   std::cout << scan_n_zeros(u2, 5U) << std::endl; // print 0
   std::cout << scan_n_zeros(u3, 4U) << std::endl; // print 1
   std::cout << scan_n_zeros(u3, 5U) << std::endl; // print 0
   std::cout << scan_n_zeros(u4, 4U) << std::endl; // print 1
   std::cout << scan_n_zeros(u4, 5U) << std::endl; // print 0
   std::cout << scan_n_zeros(u5, 4U) << std::endl; // print 1
   std::cout << scan_n_zeros(u5, 5U) << std::endl; // print 0
 }
```

Comment: would this work form uint16 so I can group two bytes into uint16 to account for the transtion from byte to the next then slide the window one byte from start to end?

Comment: @HamzaYerlikaya - I've developed a template function precisely because is intended to work with every integer unsigned type

Comment: can you expand a little bit how the bit shifting works.